# Can I coppice a cedar hedge

Tags: pruning

I have a 12' high cedar hedge. Unfortunately it is 8' wide.  I have a narrow back yard, so would like it to be only 3' wide.  Do I need to start again from seedlings, or is it possible to coppice the individual trees?  If so, then would it be possible to coppice every other tree and then do the remainder once the first batch reaches height. (I live behind a school so need that height)  I live in Victoria, Canada.  Similar climate to Seattle.

Comment: Now that I understand what you mean.  I need a picture of your tree.  I need to see that state of the lower limbs.  Are they still flexible enough with still green growth.   You need to be able to train one of those branches to be your new lead.  It should have plenty of green growth close to the stem.

Comment: @GardenGems  So it's one of the existing branches that becomes the new trunk. It's not that a new feeder comes out.

Comment: Every tree farmer I have met has always used a lower branch as the new tree, but the times colonist speaks of a method that I am not aware of.  I would give a tree farm a call.  Ask them if you can come out and see what they do.   There are always many methods to growing plants.   Start with the one in Saanichton.  Wintergreen is the one on the island I am most familiar with.  Probably the largest one on the island in Cowichan.  Ornamental nursery growers are farmers, just like most farmers they're happy to share information.